# Enforcing password rules with regex

Tags: regex

I have found regex patterns that can enforce one special sign and one digit and a minimum of characters.

But does anyone have a more realistic example of a regex for enforcing f.ex.

2 or more digits
2 or more alphabetic
2 or more non-alphabetic non-digit

Minimum length 8

Comment: The (german) articles linked from [this page](http://www.heise.de/ct/artikel/Die-Passwortknacker-1779840.html) explain pretty well, why assessing password quality with any regex will be highly inadequate. Unfortunately, these articles are behind a pay-wall...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for password requirements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615078/regex-for-password-requirements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like so:

- 2 or more digits: `\d{2,}`
- 2 or more alphabetic: `[A-Za-z]{2,}`
- 2 or more non-alphabetic: `[^A-Za-z0-9]{2,}`.

I would recommend you have seperate regular expression for different checks. This will help making a more maintainable solution. For length purposes I would recommend using the `length` property which most languages provide.

Comment: The problem with such a *simple* solution is that this will accept passwords such as "asdf..11" (provided the minimum length is 8). Any self respecting cracking tool will blow this one away in seconds, because they contain rule-sets that try for simple things such as appending "..11".

Comment: @Michael: You can run the those pattern checks on the first 8 characters from the password.

Comment: @MichaelWild: The OP simply asked for a regular expression approach to solving a particular type of problem. I can't see, at least at the time of this writing, any mentioning of cracking tools.

Comment: @npinti "*Enforcing password rules*" says it all, doesn't it? People *will* try to crack those passwords. I just wanted to caution the OP that these rules will not be sufficient to ensure good password quality.