# Password Validation With Multiple Rules

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm attempting to write a regex in PHP that validates the following:

- At least 10 chars
- Has at least 2 Upper-case characters
- Has at least 2 Numbers OR Symbols

I've looked at just about every reference I can find but, to no avail.

I guess I can test individually, but that makes me very sad :(

Can someone please help? (And send me to a spot where I can learn in plain English Reg Ex?)

Comment: "but that makes me very sad :(" --- so the solution that you can support makes you sad? What your job is about - solving the issues or writing cool and tricky code?

Comment: You can't really use a single regex to count stuff like this.  Use a more direct approach (or better yet, don't impose this sort of constraint on your users!)...

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: actually it is possible (with assertions) http://stackoverflow.com/a/1615561/251311

Comment: @zerkms: Ah, maybe it is possible with funky extensions.  Nevertheless, I imagine the resulting regex is going to be a pain to maintain...

Comment: Divide and conquer. Solve each problem individually. That is how you can solve this problem.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: yep, that's what my point in the first comment was: if you cannot think of it due to complexity - it's too early to start using it (because tomorrow you won't be able to modify it according the new requirements)

Comment: thanks everyone for your comments... it makes me sad because I am absolutely CRAP at Reg Ex and am 70% sure there should be a "one stop shop"-regex!!!

Comment: @ElGuapo you can do what you want **in one go** with RegExps (*check my answer, last part*) but you might want to rethink the whole password validation issue first

Comment: @kaᵠ it definitely works!!!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### This picture is worth more than 1000 words

*(and that's a lot of entropy)*

[image: passphrases and entropy]

*(image via XKCD)*

With this in mind you might want to consider dropping rules 2 & 3 if password length is higher than X (say.. 20) or increase the minimum to at least 16 characters (as the only rule).

---

As for your requirement:

As opposed to having one big, ugly, hard-to-maintain, advanced RegExp you might want to break the problem in smaller parts and tackle each bit separately using dedicated functions.

For this you could look at [`ctype_*` functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php), [count_chars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php) and [MultiByte String Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php).

---

Now the ugly:

This advanced RegEx will return **`true`** or **`false`** according to your rules:

```
preg_match('/^(?=.{10,}$)(?=.*?[A-Z].*?[A-Z])(?=.*?([\x20-\x40\x5b-\x60\x7b-\x7e\x80-\xbf]).*?(?1).*?$).*$/',$string);
```

Test demo here: http://regex101.com/r/qE9eB2

**1st** part (LookAhead) : `(?=.{10,}$)` will check string length and continue if it has at least 10 characters. You could drop this and do a check with [strlen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) or even better **[mb_strlen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php)**.

**2nd** part (also a LookAhead): `(?=.*?[A-Z].*?[A-Z])` will check for the presence of 2 UPPERCASE characters. You could also do a `$upper=preg_replace('/[^A-Z]/','',$string)` instead and count the chars in `$upper` to be more than two.

**3rd** LookAhead uses a character class: `[\x20-\x40\x5b-\x60\x7b-\x7e\x80-\xbf]` with hex escaped character ranges for common symbols (pretty much all the symbols one could find on an average keyboard). You could also do a `$sym=preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/','',$string)` instead and count the chars in `$sym` to be more than two. *Note: to make it shorter I used a recursive group `(?1)` to not repeat the same character class again*

For learning, the most comprehensive RegExp reference I know of is: [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: Ok... it took me about 10 minutes to stop laughing at that cartoon!!! Unfortunately I don't get to make the rules for the password rule (no pun intended), but I agree with you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookaheads to make sure that what you are looking for is contained appropriately.

```
/(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z].*[^a-zA-Z]).{10,}/
```

Answer (score 1):

I have always preferred good old procedural code for handling stuff like this. Regular expressions can be useful but they can also be a little cumbersome, especially for code maintenance and quick scanning (regular expressions are not exactly examples of readability).

```
function strContains($string, $contains, $n = 1, $exact = false) {
    $length = strlen($string);
    $tally  = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        if (strpos($contains, $string[$i]) !== false) {
            $tally++;
        }
    }
    return ($exact ? $tally == $n : $tally >= $n);
}
function validPassword($password) {
    if (strlen($password) < 10) {
        return false;
    }
    $upperChars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $upperCount = 2;
    if (strContains($password, $upperChars, $upperCount) === false) {
        return false;
    }
    $numSymChars = '0123456789!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~';
    $numSymCount = 2;
    if (strContains($password, $numSymChars, $numSymCount) === false) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```