# Regular expressions in .NET for this requirement

Tags: .net, regex, string, expression

I need a regular expression for some arguments that must match on a string.

Here it is...

1. The string exists out of minimum 8 and maximum 20 characters.
2. These characters of this string may be characters of the alphabet or special characters
   --With other words..all characters except from the white spaces
3. In the complete string there must be at least one number.
4. The string cannot start with a number or an underscore
5. The last 2 characters of the string must be identical, But it doesn’t matter if those last --identical characters are capital or non-capital (case insensitive)

**Must match all:**

```
+234567899
a_1de*Gg
xy1Me*__
!41deF_hij2lMnopq3ss
C234567890123$^67800
*5555555
sDF564zer""
!!!!!!!!!4!!!!!!!!!!
abcdefghijklmnopq9ss
```

**May not match:**

It cannot be less than 8 or more than 20 characters:

```
a_1+Eff
B41def_hIJ2lmnopq3stt
```

Cannot contain a whitespace:

```
A_4 e*gg
b41def_Hij2l nopq3ss
```

Cannot start with a number or an underscore:

```
__1+Eff
841DEf_hij2lmnopq3stt
```

Cannot end on two different characters:

```
a_1+eFg
b41DEf_hij2lmnopq3st
```

It cannot be without a number in the string:

```
abCDefghijklmnopqrss
abcdef+++dF
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
------------------------------------------------------
```

This is what I have so far...But I'm really breaking my head on this...

I just want to get in the right direction:

```
([^0-9_])(?=.*\d)(\S{8,20})(?i:[\S])\1
```

Comment: Had allot of help already... The only problem remaining is that this answer : ^[^_\s\d](?=.*\d)\S{5,17}(?i)(\S)\1$ gives 0 matches. Even in an online regex tester...I wonder if its possible with word bounderys ? thanx

Comment: Just to add the extra info...Now it does work also in my special Regex tester. In that regex tester...I could not check a checkbox witch said Multiline...so I had to add the regex paramater (?m) So the little addition ends with (?m)^[^_\s\d](?=.*\d)\S{5,17}(?i)(\S)\1$ Credits go to Paul Draper and Casimir et Hippolyte. Peace

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for password requirements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615078/regex-for-password-requirements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use multiple regexes, try these:

```
\S{8,20}

[^_0-9].*\d.*

.*(?i)(.)\1
```

If it must be one, use this:

```
^[^_\s\d](?=.*\d)\S{5,17}(?i)(\S)\1$
```

(I must give [Casmir credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758484/regular-expressions-in-net-for-this-requirement/19758608#19758608) for helping me find a bug in this last one.)

This is

1. any one character, other than an underscore, space, or digit.
2. (which must be followed by any characters and then a digit)
3. then five to seventeen non-whitespace characters
4. then (case-insensitive from now on), a whitespace character, followed by the same character

Comment: Thanks allot bro! The only problem I'm having know is that he will still find this one : 841DEf_hij2lmnopq3stt. My regex tool marks the string starting from the 'D'

Comment: Put `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end. I'm used to Java, where `.match` tests the whole string for a match.

Comment: Thanks so much. Just one little thing...is it possible that their is another way to match the whole string then the '^' and the '$' ? For some reason my regex tool suddenly doesnt find anything anymore when I add those 2 signs... Thanx allot for the help so far

Comment: Thanx paul...But how comes then every regex tester gives 0 matches ? I think im making a stupid mistake on syntax...is it possible with word bounderys ?...Do you have some time to check it out in a regex tester to for me ? cause in there it says 0 matches also ...

Comment: @Fosa, try regexhero.net/tester. It is Silverlight based. My regex works there (unfortunately, I don't think I can publish as a fiddle).

Comment: You are so kind ...I feel like a fool on this one... I uploaded a picture...whats wrong with it ? I feel nooby..                     link--> http://postimg.org/image/70tm2s6rf/

Comment: @Fosa, right now, `^` and `$` match beginning and end of *input*. If you would like to match beginning and end of line, use the Multiline regex option. (It is available in Regex Hero as a checkbox on the right.)

Comment: yes yes it's working! You are my hero!! Sorry for all the problems! Peace bro

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
^[^\s\d_](?=.*\d)\S{5,17}(?i)(\S)\1$
```