# Password validation with regular expression

Tags: regex

can any one help me in creating a regular expression for password validation for following conditions :

1. Numbers/digits are not allowed at the beginning and end but must be in middle of the string
2. Min 6, max 10 characters long
3. Special character should not allowed
4. At least one digit and two characters mandatory.

Correct format- ab21cd, stack12flow
Incorrect format- stack123, 123stack

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for password requirements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615078/regex-for-password-requirements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the pattern

```
\A[^0-9].*[^0-9]\z
```

`\A` means start of the string. `[^0-9]` means anything except numbers. `.*` means any length of characters. can be words and digits or signs. `\z` means end of string.again `[^0-9]` means should not end with numbers

If you want minimum 6 and maximum 10 characters do this

```
^[^0-9].{4,8}[^0-9]\z
```

`.` is any character. `{4,8}` specifies minimum and maximum number of `.` occurrence . since we already have 2 characters at first and last of the string then this pattern only accepts when you put `4+2` characters or maximum `8+2` characters.

Based on your comment.

```
(?=\A\w{6,10}\z)(?!\A\d|.*\d\z|.*_)(?=.*\d)
```

`(?=include)` is positive look ahead. means regex must match with part `include`.

`(?!exclude)` is negative look ahead. means regex must not match with part `exclude`.

So `(?=\A\w{6,10}\z)` means regex must have 6 up to 10 `\w` characters. `\w` can be numbers and words and underscore `_`.

`(?!\A\d|.*\d\z|.*_)` means regex must not have digit at first (`\A\d`) or (`|`) end of the string (`.*\d\z`). also it must not have `_` (`|.*_`).

`(?=.*\d)` means regex must atleast match with one digit.

You dont need to check that string must have atleast two words. because string already must be started and end with two words.

Comment: I need min 6 and maximum 10 characters. Can you please help?

Comment: @SupragyanMandal see the update. also note that `^` at start of pattern equals to `\A`. i just did it to make it a bit simpler.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. Please check my updated question I need at least one digit in middle and the whole string without special character and space.

Comment: @SupragyanMandal see the update. if you have more questions feel free to ask :)

Comment: How to not allow special characters?

Comment: special characters are not allowed here. only underscore which i removed it to. see in the negative look ahead `|.*_` will not allow `_` anymore @SupragyanMandal

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pattern.matches method (if java is the language)

```
        String reg = "[^0-9].*[^0-9]";
        String text ="12stack123stac";

        if (Pattern.matches(reg, text)) {
            System.out.println("valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("invalid");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.